# OSGi: How to add/create resources (images, xml files) in bundle at runtime?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I have bundle A which is started on osgi framework. How can I add/create resources (for example images or xml files) in this bundle at runtime - I mean bundle is installed and active? Is this possible? If yes, then how? I use apache felix.

Comment: Without reinstalling the bundle with the new content, I do not think it is possible.

Comment: @Balazs Zsoldos Do you mean the first step is to modify original bundle.jar and after that reinstall the bundle - to update in osgi cache?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that. Are you sure you can only use these XML files as classpath resources? Can't you use them from a temp folder or another store? It would be useful to know more about your use-case?

Comment: There's probably a better way to achieve what you want to do. How are the resources being loaded? Please give some background of the high-level goals.

Comment: @Balazs Zsoldos Of course there is always possibility to store these resources in another place, not in bundle. But I am looking for solution how to create them in bundle at runtime.

Comment: This is impossible because a bundle is 'logically' read only in an OSGi environment, you cannot change its content. This was explicitly done so multiple frameworks could share the same JAR. It also sounds as a bizarre thing to do, could you elaborate, as Neil asked, what you need this function for?

Comment: you may use "Apache Felix Shell" to build an interactive bundle to consume dynamic files at run time. here with examples http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-shell.html

Comment: @Hishamkh I think you have misunderstood the question.